# Paypal Adaptive payments: Who is responsible for refund?

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I would like to know who is liable if the sender ask for a refund/chargeback for either chained payment and parallel payment.

My guess:

Chained Payment: The primary receiver is 100% responsible for any refunds/chargbacks. In order to process refund from the secondary receiver, the secondary receiver must grand third-party permission to the app.

Because of that, paypal normally does not approve the platform to be the primary receiver. For example, if you take a cut on the transaction as the primary receiver and then proceed the money into the second receiver account, you can be in big trouble if the sender ask for a refund. The reason being that the primary receiver is 100% responsible but in such case, you would only have small percentage of the actual amount. If the secondary receiver does not grant you permission to process the refund, you are screwed.

Parallel payment: All receivers are responsible for refunds/chargebacks.

Any official documentation to backup a possible answer?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the exact same issue!